# Snowflake date column have incorrect date from AVRO file

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have HIVE external table created in AVRO format. Data stored on S3 location. Now i am creating snowflake table on same data file stored on s3 in avro format. But getting issue with date column. Date is not coming correctly although string and int data are coming correctly in snowflake table.

data in hive table( col1 is timestamp data type in hive table):

col1
2021-02-04 10:02:31

data in snowflake table:

col1
53066-07-15 12:56:40.000

sql to create snowflake table:

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE test1
(
col1 timestamp as (value:col1::timestamp),
)
WITH  LOCATION = @S3_location/folder/
AUTO_REFRESH =  TRUE
FILE_FORMAT = 'AVRO';"

Comment: A couple of thoughts: (1) Is your Avro file compressed? (2) If you set the datatype to varchar, rather than timestamp, does it display a value that you corresponds to the underlying stored value equivalent to the required timestamp value?

Comment: Avro file is not compressed. On second point, when i set datatype to varchar it display value but that is not correspond to actual timestamp value. So i pick one value and check corresponding timestamp as select to_timestamp(1285905600000) which is not matched with correct date. Now i have removed last three zeros as check as select to_timestamp(1285905600) which give me correct date but four hours ahead of time. I feel something went wrong when avro file read by snowflake external table. Or may be some fix need to apply while creating external snowflake table.

Comment: I'm guessing the difference is timezone-related. What timezone do you think it should be (or is it UTC)? What do you have session parameter TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING set to? If I run "select to_timestamp(1285905600)" I get the value "2010-10-01 04:00:00.000" - is that what you get?

Comment: So i can understand 4 hours time difference due to time zone. now on date part actual data from avro file i am getting after changing to varchar from timestamp is select to_timestamp(1285905600000) which is giving wrong date. correct date i am getting after i removed last three zeros and run select to_timestamp(1285905600) in snowflake. Hive table shows up correct date but snowflake table created on same avro file giving me wrong date(very far future date). I feel avro date column has different behavior when read by hive and snowflake external table or need to check how avro store date data.